# What does the process control block of a child process look like after a fork?

Tags: process, fork

My understanding is that when a parent forks, the child becomes an exact copy of the parent. In other words, they have the same process control block (PCB). Is this completely correct? I know that the `pid` will obviously be different but is that it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each process has its own process control block.  When the parent forks the child's process control block will normally start as a duplicate of the parent however it is changed (for instance one of the first is the PID) and as the child does its own thing, the child's process control block will become less of a duplicate of the parent.

Here are some [slides that describes an abstract operating system process control and the process control block](http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse451/07wi/lectures/4-process.pdf).

The actual specifics will vary depending on the particular operating system.

Comment: So, after creation, the child has exact copies of memory, registers, open files, etc?

Comment: @MaxMackie, perhaps you should explain a bit more about why you are asking this question.  If it is a matter of wanting to understand the concepts then whether it is exact or not should not matter.  My expectation is that memory and file control blocks of open files will be the same however registers will not and there will be other pieces that will begin to vary almost immediately after the process control block is duplicated since the child process will begin doing other things.